# Automatically add slash when navigating through symlink

Tags: bash, symlink, autocomplete, cd-command

I use symlinks a lot and pretty much linked my whole home directory into a folder `.other` or `.dotfiles`. When I'm im my home directory and try to got into the folder `.config/`, its actually a symbolic link to `.other/.config/`. 
If `.config/` was a normal directory I could just type `cd .con` and hit *tab*. Bash would automatically expand it to `.config/` (as long as there are no other files/directories starting with `.con`). Unfortunately bash has this little hurdle, when navigating through symlinks: Bash only expands to `.config` (not `.config/`) and I have to hit *tab* another time to add the `/` (to got further).
This is just minor, but is there a possibility to get bash to add a slash even after symlink expansion?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set the `mark-symlinked-directories` readline option.

The usual way to do this is to edit `~/.inputrc`, put

```
set mark-symlinked-directories on
```

in there, then start a new bash shell (or press <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> to reload your readline settings).

Less commonly, you could also put it straight in your `~/.bashrc` like this

```
bind 'set mark-symlinked-directories on'
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! Is the `~/.inputrc` a part of bash or where does it belong to? Can I add it to my `~/.bash_profile` instead?

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work in `~/.bash_profile`. No problem just another file for `.dotfiles`...

Comment: You can actually do `bind 'set mark-symlinked-directories on'` in any `bash` config file (or in the bash shell) if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Would be a little unpleasant to create a new file for just one line of code...